# Rails 6 migration add foreign key association between existing tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two tables `talks` and `media`.

1. The `talks` may have 0 or 1 `media`.
2. The `media` can have other rows that is not associated to any `talks`.

I'm planning to add a foreign key to the `talks` table to a field `media_id` (that references `media`), so that if `media` is deleted, `media_id` would be null. Though not super necessary, it'd be great to have the associated `media` to be deleted when `talks` row is deleted, if any.

The current migration looks like, it runs fine and generates the `media_id` on the `talks` table as I want:

```
class AddMediaToTalks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :talks, :media, type: :integer, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

But, I'm not so sure about what I need to put on the models, I mean `has_one` and `belongs_to`. I am not sure which would go to which model, or even if I need only one or neither or both.

I also tried adding `on_delete: :nullify` to the migration script, but it doesn't really have any effect. I'm using `mysql`, btw. When I try to delete associated `media`, it fails because it is referenced in the  `talks` table.

`Disclaimer` : I am fairly new to Rails. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put the foreign key into talks that means talks belongs to media (because it can only belong to one media (the `media_id` column in `talks` can only hold one value/one id).

In the Rails guide you find some more information on how to choose between belongs_to and has_one, the main indicator is in which table you place the foreign key. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one (Depending on your use case you might want to say a talk has a medium(?) and change it around again - but that would mean to change the migration too!).

If you want to delete the media when the talk is deleted just add `dependent: :destroy` to the talk model:

```
class Talk
  belongs_to :media, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And for this problem:

> When I try to delete associated media, it fails because it is referenced in the calls table.

That means you're missing the `dependent: :destroy` in the `calls` model, (if deleting all associated media when deleting a call is if what you want). Alternatively, you could also delete media first and then calls.

Comment: Thanks. I got over the delete media issue by using `add_column` and `add_foreign_key` with `on_delete: :nullify`. I was talking about database-level, and the correct cascading is applied, but was not applied with `add_reference`. Also, there was a typo in the initial entry, I meant `talks` instead of `calls`

Comment: When you said `talk has a medium` and `change the migration`, do you mean having `call_id` in `media` table` ? I'd avoid that because the `media` table could contain all sorts of other values as well that has absolutely nothing do with `calls`.

Comment: I was refering to the Rails guide that says "you should give some thought to the actual meaning of the data as well." on how to decide where to put belongs to. I don't know what your app is about so maybe following the real word example it makes more sense to say `a talk has a medium (a media?)` instead of `a medium has a talk`. But of course other reasons can play a role too and the one you mentioned is perfectly fine!

Comment: Yep makes sense. I want to stick with having the reference of `media` in `talks`. On the issue of deleting associated `media` when deleting `talk`, `belongs_to :media, dependent: :destroy` didn't really work.

Comment: I got no error. It turns out I had used `.delete`, `.destroy` seems to work. I'm reading the documentation, but it's starting to get blurry on their differences.

Comment: Yes, `delete` just deletes the record without any callbacks or in this case destroying the dependent/associated records. `destroy` does it!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the clarifications. So, putting in `has_one :talk` makes sense on the `media` model? without the `dependent: :destroy` since I don't want to delete the `talk` when delete a `media`?

Comment: Right. You can leave it or if you want to explictly clarify you can put `dependent: nullify`. Means nullify the `media_id` field in `talks` when deleting a media. (This way a linter like rubocop won't complain - they like it explicit).

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks.